# I don't quite understand the derivative in this vertical wind gust formula

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, performance-calculation, windshear

First my english writing skill is still bad so pardon me if i accidentally made any mistake TT-TT.
So recently I have learnt about how the vertical gust affect the load factor and the calculation behind it, here are the formula in the slides:
[image][image]

[image]
So in the third picture I was wondering what dose the derivative of DCl/Da really mean and how these two derivative in the third picture equal.
It's frustrated how I dont understand that, please help me.

Comment: I don't understand TT minus TT ...

Comment: It seems to be saying the vertical gust causes a change in relative wind, which affects the Coefficient of Lift by changing the angle of attack in the same way as the elevator would in calm air.  So go on to tan alpha gust = u/V = change in AoA (therefor Clift) from gust.